# template parameter to boost multi index container

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-multi-index

I need to create a generic class containing multiindex container as a storage. when I compile, it gives error as below where I have defined nth index view.

error: non-template ‘nth_index’ used as template

```
/**
 * connection manager
 */
```

template < typename T, typename C >
class conn_mgr: boost::noncopyable {
public:
    /**
     * connection ptr
     */
    typedef boost::shared_ptr conn_ptr_t;
    /**
     * connection table type
     * It's a multi index container
     */
    typedef  boost::multi_index::multi_index_container <
            conn_ptr_t,
            boost::multi_index::indexed_by <
                    //sequenced < >,
                    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique <
                            BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(T, std::string, T::id)  >,
                    boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique <
                            BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(T, std::string,
                                    T::type)>,
                    boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique <
                            boost::multi_index::composite_key < conn_ptr_t,
                                    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(T,
                                            std::string, T::id),
                                    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(T,
                                            std::string, T::type ) > > > >
            conn_table_t;

```
//typedef for ConnectionIdView
typedef conn_table_t::nth_index<0>::type conn_table_by_id_type;

typedef conn_table_t::nth_index<1>::type conn_table_by_type;

typedef conn_table_t::nth_index<2>::type conn_table_by_id_type;
```

private:
        conn_table_t conn_table_;
 };

and here how I am using in main.

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   typedef conn_mgr < smpp_conn, smpp_config > smpp_conn_mgr_t;
   smpp_conn_mgr_t conn_mgr;
}

Comment: You can't typedef a template. This line is invalid: `typedef boost::shared_ptr conn_ptr_t;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this syntax instead for your nested typedefs:

```
typedef typename conn_table_t::template nth_index<0>::type conn_table_by_id_type;
```

The `typename` keyword is used here as a qualifier to let the compiler know that `conn_table_t::template nth_index<0>::type` is a type. This special use of `typename` is only necessary within templates.

The `template` keyword is used here as a qualifier to distingush member templates from other names.

---

Furthermore, this line is invalid:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr conn_ptr_t;
```

You can't typedef templates. You can only typedef types. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
typedef typename boost::shared_ptr<T> conn_ptr_t;
```

---

One last error: You're attempting to give two typedefs the same name: `conn_table_by_id_type`

---

You should use `BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(T, std::string, id)` instead of `BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(T, std::string, T::id)`, as documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#boost_multi_index_const_mem_fun).

---

In response to your last comment: This snippet compiles for me:

```
void foo(std::string id)
{
    conn_table_by_id_type& id_type_view = conn_table_.template get<0>();
    typename conn_table_by_id_type::const_iterator it = id_type_view.find(id);
}
```

Where `foo` is a member function inside the `conn_mgr` template. I'm guessing that the above is what you were trying to do.

You should write helper methods that get references to your three different `conn_table_` indices. This will make things much more concise. For example:

```
conn_table_by_id_type & by_id_type() {return conn_table_.template get<0>();}

void foo2(std::string id)
{
    typename conn_table_by_id_type::const_iterator it = by_id_type().find(id);
}
```

Comment: Emile, thx a lot. Also I learnt a lesson of using typename. Eg. When I tried std::vector<T>::iterator, it gave error but once I converted to typename std::vector<T>::iterator, it worked.

Comment: Hi Emile, now when I use the conm_mgr class as shown above, I get error "No type named "T" in class smpp_conn.  I am passing "smpp_conn" class object as first template parameter "T" in conn_mgr class.

Comment: @Emile: that worked.  Need one more help. How do I find and iterator? e.g typedef typename conn_table_t::template nth_index<0>::type conn_table_by_id_type; conn_table_by_id_type *id_type_view; typename conn_table_by_id_type::const_iterator it = id_type_view->find(id); gives error on scalar conversion for it.

Comment: @rjoshi: You can't invoke methods on the uniniatized pointer `*id_type_view`. See revised answer.

Comment: @Emile: thx. I was getting iterator from index 2 and assigning to id_view which is index 1. But I like you idea of creating a wrapper function. Thx a lot again.